# access itunes via my own app

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes

I'm newbie at this, so question - 
I'm trying to create app which should be similar to native ipad/iphone reader. And I want users are be able to buy books via my app in itunes. I mean, apple approve new book, than user opens app, press smth like "buy" button and goes to app's page which contains approved book in itunes, than he can buy it using itune's account. is it possible to do?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Everything you draft already exists within Apple's iTunes. Do you plan to create a reader or an alternative store frontend?

Comment: Company has some special books format, so they want to create reader for it and sell books via itunes. I'm planning to get approved books from itunes in app(likely via url schema) and show it for user(sorted, groupped etc). I don't want to create an alternative store so I want to pick up books from itunes directly, so user can buy it under the same itune's account

Comment: That would be a classic case for regular in-app-purchase and has nothing todo with apples bookstore if the only way to read those books is using your custom app.

Comment: and there are no ways to send own's books in bookstore? Aim is do all unified: put the books on store, buy it and read using custom reader..if we use third-party mechanism instead of bookstore, there are arising some troubles - with payments and so on

Comment: In-App-Purchase is not a third-party mechanism. See [Apple's introduction](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4009?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't open iTunes in your app..not only iTunes but any other app on the device..
You can just open them with URL schemes if the other app has one..

Comment: I may be nitpicking but sure enough you can invoke iTunes from an app. Just, it won't be returning to your app afterwards.

Comment: I mean 2 things: first, just receive books from itunes with params like "from that company", "from date...to date..." And the second - user should be able to buy it via his itune's account